# Polymer - iron-ajax - google sheets JSON data binding

Tags: json, google-sheets, polymer

Polymer newbie here..

Trying to setup a repeater for some HTML for data sitting in a google sheets document, by getting its JSON data..

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1jJxd4Q3MzZLxMZ4pO9E56UL4eZInuPNwUdrFXk9qds8/od6/public/values?alt=json

Im trying to use:

```
// Load the JSON file from Google
<iron-ajax auto url="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1jJxd4Q3MzZLxMZ4pO9E56UL4eZInuPNwUdrFXk9qds8/od6/public/values?alt=json"
               handle-as="json"
               last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

//Create the HTML repeater to list the image items
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
      <a href="{{feed.entry.item.gsx$imageurl.$t}}"><img src="{{feed.entry.item.gsx$imagethumburl.$t}}" data-big="{{feed.entry.item.gsx$imageurl.$t}}" data-title="{{feed.entry.item.gsx$imagetitle.$t}}" data-description="{{feed.entry.item.gsx$imagecaption.$t}}" ></a>
    </template>
```

But, I cant seem to target inside the JSON feed>entry>row number

My console keeps saying :

polymer-micro.html:277 [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found Object {version: "1.0", encoding: "UTF-8", feed: Object}

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code.

Firstly, once you are within the `dom-repeat`, you must refer to the current item simply as `item`. If you want, you can change the variable name with applying the `as` attribute onto the `dom-repeat` element.

Secondly, when using `dom-repeat`, the `items` property must be an actual array. In your case, you are using the whole JSON response. You should change it to `items="{{data.feed.entry}}"`.

This said, the final code should look like this:

```
// Load the JSON file from Google
<iron-ajax auto url="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1jJxd4Q3MzZLxMZ4pO9E56UL4eZInuPNwUdrFXk9qds8/od6/public/values?alt=json"
               handle-as="json"
               last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

//Create the HTML repeater to list the image items
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data.feed.entry}}">
  <a href="{{item.gsx$imageurl.$t}}"><img src="{{item.gsx$imagethumburl.$t}}" data-big="{{item.gsx$imageurl.$t}}" data-title="{{item.gsx$imagetitle.$t}}" data-description="{{item.gsx$imagecaption.$t}}" ></a>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you alesc. Polymer has been a steep learning curve. Really appreciate it.